# Conversion of IDOCs to XML format at SAP Level

Tags: idoc

Is there a way to replace the legacy text IDoc files with XML IDoc files when dealing with SAP?

If so would it be something that is provided by the SAP or we have to use a third party library to do that?

Is it a good practice to do it (than using the legacy IDoc files), and would it have a adverse performance hit?

Help appreciated.

Comment: ok, i found the answe.. and yes there is! 
www.erpgenie.com/.../Conversion%20of%20IDOCs%20to%20XML%20format.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is answered in [Conversion of IDOCs to XML format at SAP Level](http://www.erpgenie.com/sap/sapedi/Conversion%20of%20IDOCs%20to%20XML%20format.pdf)